# Issue with websites viewport

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mobile

Kinda broad question but I've got something wrong in regards to my website's (https://huskybiz.com) viewport. I'm trying to format it to look good at all viewport sizes. The issue is with the mobile formatting. I try adding the standard viewport meta tag

```
<meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content= "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

However this results in only a portion of my website being shown on mobile with the rest flowing off the screen, as shown here:

[image: when initial sclae=1.0]

As of now my solution has been to make the initial-scale = 0. I know when the initial-scale=1 there is no initial scale so I honestly don't know what having it equal means but it does make my entire website scale onto the mobile devices. However with this fix when you first load the website my nav bar does strange things where it starts out 1/2 the width of the viewport before quickly clipping to 100% of it, as shown:

[image: first second of loading]

[image: two seconds after loading]

Other than that I have my html and body css like this:

```
html,body {
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
width: auto;
min-width: 800px;
max-width: 2000px;
height: auto;
min-height: 100%;
```

}

My two concerns are I don't understand why the initial-width doesn't work when equal to one when from I believe it should, and why my fix has my nav doing that clipping. The min-width of the html is 800 really just for desktops when people try to scale the window too narrow but that might be part of the problem otherwise my nav bar is fixed so it can be hidden/shown while scrolling. That seems to play a role too. Otherwise I'm stumped. Thanks for any help.

Comment: why not use `width:100vw` that should take care for all devices?

Comment: You've got a `min-width: 800px` on `body` which isn't helping matters.

Comment: Your original view port setting wasn't the problem. The problem is that your other contents should be adapting different width better. You carousel, for example, should scale down to the width of the mobile screen.

Comment: You should first read about [responsiveness and media query](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp). Then you should replace the components that are not responsive (e.g. use [slick](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) for carousel) and fix the css.